# Generate a correct scrapy hidden input form values for asp doPostBack() function

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

**tldr;** My attempts to overwritte the hidden field needed by server to return me a new page of geocaches failed (**__EVENTTARGET** attributes) , so server return me an empty page.

Ps : My original post was closed du to vote abandon, so i repost here after a the massive edit i produce on the first post.

---

I try to scrap some webpages which contain cache on a famous geocaching site using `Scrapy 1.5.0`.

Because you need an account if you want to run this [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shira8Vcdr6OaUsuDDOcEqG_2V54vSRv/view?usp=sharing), i create a new temporary and free account on the website to make some test : `dumbuser` with password `stackoverflow`

---

**A) The actual working part of the process :**

- First, i enter the website by login page (needed to search page) : `https://www.geocaching.com/account/login`
- After successful login, i search item ([geocaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocaching)) in some geographic places (for exemple `France, Haute-Normandie`).

This first search works without problem, and i have no difficulties to parse the first geocaches.

**B) The problem part of the process : requesting next pages**

When i try to simulate a click to go to the **next page** of geocaches. For example going to page 1 to page 2.

[image]

The website use [ASP with synchronised state between client and server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), so we need to go to page1 then page2 then page3 then etc. during the scrap in order to maintain the `__VIEWSTATE` variable (an hidden input) generated by server between each FORM query.

The link of each number (see the image) call a link with javascript function `javascript:__doPostBack(...)`, which inject content into already existing hidden field before submitting the entire form.

As you can see in the `__doPostBack` function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Exemple : 
So when you click on page 2 link, javascript run is `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentBody$pgrTop$lbGoToPage_2','')`. The form is submitted with

- `__EVENTTARGET = ctl00$ContentBody$pgrTop$lbGoToPage_2`
- `__EVENTARGUMENT = ''`

**C) First try to imitate this behavior :**

In order to scrap many pages (limited here to five first pages) i try here to `yield` five  `formRequest.from_response` query which simply overwrite manually this `__EVENTTARGET` `__EVENTARGUMENT` attribute :

```
def parse_pages(self,response):

    self.parse_cachesList(response)

    ## EXTRACT NUMBER OF PAGES
    links = response.xpath('//td[@class="PageBuilderWidget"]/span/b[3]')
    print(links.extract_first())

    ## Try to extract page 1 to 5 for exemple
    for page in range(1,5):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath="//form[@id='aspnetForm']",
            formdata=
{'__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentBody$pgrTop$lbGoToPage_'+str(page),
'__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                      '__LASTFOCUS': ''},
            dont_click=True,
            callback=self.parse_cachesList,
            dont_filter=True
        )
```

**D) Consequence :**

The page returned by server is empty, so there is something wrong in my strategy.

When i look at the generated html code returned by server after form post, the `__EVENTTARGET` **is never overwritten by scrapy** :

```
<input id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

**E) Question :**

Could you help me to understand why scrapy don't replace/overwrite the `__EVENTTARGET` value here ? Where is the problem in my strategy to simulate users who click to follow each new pages ?

**Complete code is downloadable here** : [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shira8Vcdr6OaUsuDDOcEqG_2V54vSRv/view?usp=sharing)

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

Using fiddler, i finally found that the problem is linked to an input : `ctl00$ContentBody$chkAll=Check All` This input is automatically copied by scrapy.FormRequest.from_response method. If i remove this attribute from POST request, it works. So, how can i remove this field, i try empty without result :

```
result = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname="aspnetForm",
            formxpath="//form[@id='aspnetForm']",
            formdata={'ctl00$ContentBody$chkAll':'',
                      '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentBody$pgrTop$lbGoToPage_2',},
            dont_click=True,
            callback=self.parse_cachesList,
            dont_filter=True,
            meta={'proxy': 'http://localhost:8888'}
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved** using lot of patience, and [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool to debug and resend the POST query to the server !

Like **update 1** say in my original question, the problem comes from the input `ctl00$ContentBody$chkAll` in the form.

The way to remove an input into the POST form sent by `FormRequest` is simple, i found it in the [commit here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2721). Set the attribute to `None` in the `formdata` dictionnary.

```
    result = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname="aspnetForm",
        formxpath="//form[@id='aspnetForm']",
        formdata={'ctl00$ContentBody$chkAll':None,
        '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentBody$pgrTop$lbGoToPage_2',},
        dont_click=True,
        callback=self.parse_cachesList,
        dont_filter=True
        )
```